# Why is my CStatic derived class does not receive OnMouseLeave event but can receive OnMouseMove

Tags: c++, mfc

The code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestClass.h"
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(TestClass, CStatic)
TestClass::TestClass()
{

}
void TestClass::Ini(CWnd* parent)
{
    Create(L"hello world",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_CENTER | SS_NOTIFY , 
    CRect(0,0,50,50), parent, 200);
}
void TestClass::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
     CStatic::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
void TestClass::OnMouseLeave()
{
     CStatic::OnMouseLeave();
}
TestClass::~TestClass()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(TestClass, CStatic)
ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
ON_WM_MOUSELEAVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

As you can see I'm using SS_NOTIFY and I can not get the OnMouseLeave event, but OnMouseMove working without any problems.
Note:
I creating a custom window so I removed the title bar.

Comment: You are assuming it calls TrackMouseEvent().  It doesn't.

Comment: thanks man, you should put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the mouse leave and mouse hover event you have to call TrackMouseEvent in the OnMouseMove function.

```
void TestClass::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT MouseBehaviour;

    CStatic::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);

    MouseBehaviour.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
    MouseBehaviour.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
    MouseBehaviour.hwndTrack = GetSafeHwnd();
    MouseBehaviour.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;

    TrackMouseEvent(&MouseBehaviour);
}
```